# how to call visualforce page from trigger?

Tags: apex

I need to show a popup based on condition like in Contact object if Relationship(custom field) value is 'primary' is changing his address then a popup should be visible which shows all contacts of same account with checkboxes. 
and asks a question you want to copy this address to these contacts? 
if user click save then that address will be copied to checked contacts.

So, I need trigger to check condition first and based on result i need to show popup.
can anyone please how could i achieve this.

Comment: Sorry to say. The approach is incorrect. There is no way as of now using which you can land on a VF page or launch one from trigger.

Comment: Yes actually I want to display the VisualForce page attached with controller when I Edit the address field on the standard object "Contact"  please can you suggest any alternative to this.                                                                                   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about adding functionality to a page (responding to what the user clicks etc.) which means you should be looking at a controller or controller extension. Not a trigger.

Comment: You're right. Trying to do this with a trigger is the wrong approach

Comment: is there is any other way to do this?

Comment: I need a popup based on condition if contact is updating his address, and that popup contain some checkboxes

Comment: Assuming that your user is on a VF page, making some update then you could use a controller, or controller extension. This would let you implement some custom logic to query the data and return something which drives the creation of the popup if appropriate.

Comment: Actually I am using standard page i.e contact object page and not any VF page and i need to check some condition on fields after or before save of contacts. and based on that i need to show a popup i.e VF page .                                     Can you please suggest any way to achieve this???

Comment: One way could be to introduce a new button "change address" which leads to a small VF page allowing the address change to be done and making the checks.